# Why does the second version of this run in exponential time?

Tags: haskell, time-complexity, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting

I am writing a program to determine if the Levenshtein distance between two strings is exactly 2 in linear time.

I have an algorithm which does this.  I use the naive recursive approach which scans the string and when it finds a discrepancy it branches into 3 options trying either to delete, insert or replace.  However I make a modification that if we exceed 2 as our total we just give up on that branch.  This limits the total number of branches to 9 and makes the algorithm linear.

Here's my initial implementation:

```hs
diffIs2 x y =
  2 == go 0 x y
  where
    go total xs@(x1:xs') ys@(y1:ys')
      | x1 == y1
      =
        go total xs' ys'
      | total < 2
      =
        minimum $ zipWith (go $ total + 1)
          [ xs', xs , xs' ]
          [ ys , ys', ys' ]
    go total xs ys =
      total + length xs + length ys
```

Testing confirms that this runs in linear time.

I also have a second similar program which as far as I can tell should be linear as well.

The idea here is to use short circuiting and lazy evaluation to limit the number of branches evaluated instead.  We always allow a branching however, when we branch we take the minimum of the result of each and 3.  That way if the branch total exceeds 3 the short circuit should prevent further evaluation.

We have to implement a natural number type for partial evaluation.

```hs
data Nat
  = Zero
  | Succ Nat
  deriving
    ( Eq
    , Ord
    )

natLength :: [a] -> Nat
natLength [] =
  Zero
natLength (a : b) =
  Succ (natLength b)

nat3 =
  Succ $ Succ $ Succ Zero

diffIs2 x y =
  Succ (Succ Zero) == go x y
  where
    go xs@(x1:xs') ys@(y1:ys')
      | x1 == y1
      =
        go xs' ys'
      | otherwise
      =
        Succ $
          minimum $
            map (min nat3) $
              zipWith go
                [ xs', xs , xs' ]
                [ ys , ys', ys' ]
    go xs ys =
      natLength $ xs ++ ys
```

Testing this reveals it doesn't run in linear time.  Something makes it exponential but I can't figure out what.  The short circuiting does work as expected.  We can show this with the following program which halts in finite time because of the short circuiting of `min`:

```hs
f = Succ f

main =
  print $ (Succ Zero) == min (Succ Zero) f
```

but when put together in the algorithm it doesn't seem to work as I expect.

Why is the second code exponential?  What is my misconception?

Comment: `f = Succ f` is an infinite recursion of `Succ f`, so `Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (...))))))`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, that is the intention.  Because of lazy evaluation that program halts in finite time while if it were strict it would loop forever.

Comment: I am unsure, but I'd guess `minimum` is not lazy enough to enable short-circuiting. `minimum ys` will fully scan `ys` in all cases. Most importantly `minimum [Succ f, Succ f]` is not `Succ f` (i.e., `f`), where `f` is your infinity value. You might need a custom `minimum` which will return `Succ` early, before digging deep into the values, when possible (i.e. when no  `Zero` is found).

Comment: ``Succ Zero `min` (Succ undefined)`` diverges, even though we _know_ it should be `Succ Zero`. could it be that your `nat3` actually sets the branching factor of 4? could it be that, giving you this big constant factor slowdown, or have you actually absolutely positively detected the _exponential_ growth?

Comment: @WillNess I can't be certain of much with asymptotic complexity, however the growth is more consistent with exponential complexity than linear complexity, and I can say that having run a version of algorithm 1 with a branching factor of 4 that it is much faster than the below algorithm.

Answer (score 9):

While the default `min` is lazy enough for your simple example at the end of your question, it is not as lazy as we would hope:

```
ghci> let inf = Succ inf
ghci> inf `min` inf `min` Zero == Zero
^CInterrupted.
```

To fix it we need a lazier `min`:

```
min' :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
min' Zero _ = Zero
min' _ Zero = Zero
min' (Succ x) (Succ y) = Succ (min' x y)
```

The big difference is that now we can get a partial result before evaluating the arguments completely:

```
min (Succ undefined) (Succ undefined) === undefined
min' (Succ undefined) (Succ undefined) === Succ (min' undefined undefined)
```

Now we can use it as follows:

```
diffIs2 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
diffIs2 x y = Succ (Succ Zero) == go x y
  where
    go xs@(x1:xs') ys@(y1:ys')
      | x1 == y1 = go xs' ys'
      | otherwise = Succ $ go xs' ys `min'` go xs ys' `min'` go xs' ys'
    go xs ys = natLength $ xs ++ ys
```

Note that you do not even really need the extra `min' nat3`, because the top level comparison will only force the first three `Succ`s anyway.

Comment: I see how `min` is not as lazy as it could be and I see how the fix works, but I am still struggling to understand exactly why my code doesn't work.  In the provided code, since `min nat3` is mapped across the list, the code never taking the `min` in any case where both inputs might be longer than 3.  As demonstrated by the example `min nat3` won't evaluate the entire expression.

Comment: @ÉamonnOlive that is a good question. I believe it is because each branch will itself branch and in that branch the limit of 3 is reset. And the `Succ`s are not immediately propagated, only a single `Succ` is propagated and it is only propagated a single level. So it will only reach the limit of 3 once it reaches the end of the input. It would be nice to show how this evaluates in practice, but it gets very messy very quickly.